# java tic tac toe computer player

Tags: java, user-interface, tic-tac-toe

im making a tictactoe game but it needs to be able to have the Computer make a move, ive tried making another method computerTurn() that if(playerturn == false) would make buttons == "O" and then use nested if statments to check for where the player has put "X" and based on that make new moves but the first one i tried didnt do anything i think it might be because the buttons are all in  public voids but im a little stumped on this any one have any ideas, 
ill post the code i have but theres quite a lot so ill only post the part with the buttons and move making. if you need more code to figure it out let me know and ill post it asap.
"also i have 2 classes made tictactoe class holds the buttons and GUI setup and main class is mostly winchecks and setups for the booleans"
TICTACTOE CLASS

```
    package game;

import static game.main.playerturn;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class tictactoe extends JFrame 
{
    main Main = new main();

        public tictactoe() {
                initComponents();
        }
    public void computerTurn()
    {
        tictactoe Tictactoe = new tictactoe();

        if( main.playerturn == false)
        {
            button5.setText("O");
            main.wincheck();
            main.playerturn = true;
        }
    }

        public void button1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (button1.getText().equals(""))
            {
//               computerTurn(); 
               if (main.playerturn == true)
               {
                   button1.setText("X");
                   main.wincheck();
                   main.playerturn = false;
               }
               else
               {
                   button1.setText("O");
                   main.wincheck();
                   main.playerturn = true;
               }
            }
        }

        public void button2ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            if (button2.getText().equals(""))
            {
               if (main.playerturn == true)
               {
                   button2.setText("X");
                   main.wincheck();
                   main.playerturn = false;
               }
               else
               {
                   button2.setText("O");
                   main.wincheck();
                   main.playerturn = true;
               }
            }
        }

        public void button3ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (button3.getText().equals(""))
            {
               if (main.playerturn == true)
               {
                   button3.setText("X");
                   main.wincheck();
                   main.playerturn = false;
               }
               else
               {
                   button3.setText("O");
                   main.wincheck();
                   main.playerturn = true;
               }
            }
        }

        public void button4ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (button4.getText().equals(""))
            {
               if (main.playerturn == true)
               {
                   button4.setText("X");
                   main.wincheck();
                   main.playerturn = false;
               }
               else
               {
                   button4.setText("O");
                   main.wincheck();
                   main.playerturn = true;
               }
            }
        }

        public void button5ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (button5.getText().equals(""))
            {
               if (main.playerturn == true)
               {
                   button5.setText("X");
                   main.wincheck();
                   main.playerturn = false;
               }
               else
               {
                   button5.setText("O");
                   main.wincheck();
                   main.playerturn = true;
               }
            }
        }

        public void button6ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (button6.getText().equals(""))
            {
               if (main.playerturn == true)
               {
                   button6.setText("X");
                   main.wincheck();
                   main.playerturn = false;
               }
               else
               {
                   button6.setText("O");
                   main.wincheck();
                   main.playerturn = true;
               }
            }

        }

        public void button7ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (button7.getText().equals(""))
            {
               if (main.playerturn == true)
               {
                   button7.setText("X");
                   main.wincheck();
                   main.playerturn = false;
               }
               else
               {
                   button7.setText("O");
                   main.wincheck();
                   main.playerturn = true;
               }
            }
        }

        public void button8ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            if (button8.getText().equals(""))
            {
               if (main.playerturn == true)
               {
                   button8.setText("X");
                   main.wincheck();
                   main.playerturn = false;
               }
               else
               {
                   button8.setText("O");
                   main.wincheck();
                   main.playerturn = true;
               }
            }
        }

        public void button9ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (button9.getText().equals(""))
            {
               if (main.playerturn == true)
               {
                   button9.setText("X");
                   main.wincheck();
                   main.playerturn = false;
               }
               else
               {
                   button9.setText("O");
                   main.wincheck();
                   main.playerturn = true;
               }
            }
        }
        //computer turn*****
//    public void computerTurn()
//    {
//        tictactoe Tictactoe = new tictactoe();
//                
//        if( playerturn == false)
//        {
//            button5.setText("O");
//            main.wincheck();
//            main.playerturn = true;
//        }
//        
//        
//    }

        public void initComponents() 
        {
                button1 = new JButton();
                button2 = new JButton();
                button3 = new JButton();
                button4 = new JButton();
                button5 = new JButton();
                button6 = new JButton();
                button7 = new JButton();
                button8 = new JButton();
                button9 = new JButton();

                setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
                Container contentPane = getContentPane();

                //---- button1 ----
                button1.setText("");
                button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                        {
                                button1ActionPerformed(e);
                        }
                });

                //---- button2 ----
                button2.setText("");
                button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                        {
                                button2ActionPerformed(e);
                        }
                });

                //---- button3 ----
                button3.setText("");
                button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                        {
                                button3ActionPerformed(e);
                        }
                });

                //---- button4 ----
                button4.setText("");
                button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                        {
                                button4ActionPerformed(e);
                        }
                });

                //---- button5 ----
                button5.setText("");
                button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                        {
                                button5ActionPerformed(e);
                        }
                });

                //---- button6 ----
                button6.setText("");
                button6.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                        {
                                button6ActionPerformed(e);
                        }
                });

                //---- button7 ----
                button7.setText("");
                button7.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                        {
                                button7ActionPerformed(e);
                        }
                });

                //---- button8 ----
                button8.setText("");
                button8.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                        {
                                button8ActionPerformed(e);
                        }
                });

                //---- button9 ----
                button9.setText("");
                button9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                        {
                                button9ActionPerformed(e);
                        }
                });

                GroupLayout contentPaneLayout = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
                contentPane.setLayout(contentPaneLayout);
                contentPaneLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                        contentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup()
                                .addGroup(contentPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addContainerGap()
                                        .addGroup(contentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup()
                                                .addGroup(contentPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                        .addComponent(button1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                        .addComponent(button2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                        .addComponent(button3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                                .addGroup(contentPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                        .addComponent(button4, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                        .addComponent(button5, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                        .addComponent(button6, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                                .addGroup(contentPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                        .addComponent(button7, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                        .addComponent(button8, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                        .addComponent(button9, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                        .addContainerGap(11, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                );
                contentPaneLayout.setVerticalGroup(
                        contentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup()
                                .addGroup(contentPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addContainerGap()
                                        .addGroup(contentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                .addComponent(button1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addComponent(button2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addComponent(button3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addGroup(contentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                .addComponent(button4, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addComponent(button5, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addComponent(button6, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addGroup(contentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                .addComponent(button7, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addComponent(button8, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addComponent(button9, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addContainerGap(15, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                );
                pack();
                setLocationRelativeTo(getOwner());
        }

        public JButton button1;
        public JButton button2;
        public JButton button3;
        public JButton button4;
        public JButton button5;
        public JButton button6;
        public JButton button7;
        public JButton button8;
        public JButton button9;
}
```

MAIN CLASS

```
package game;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class main
{
    public static boolean playerturn = false;
    public static boolean computerturn = true;
    public static boolean playerwon = false;
    public static boolean computerwon = false;

    public static tictactoe board = new tictactoe();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if (board.isVisible() == false)
        {
            board.setVisible(true);
        }

    }

//    public static void computerTurn()
//    {
//        tictactoe Tictactoe = new tictactoe();
//                
//        if( playerturn == false)
//        {
//            button5.setText("O");
//            main.wincheck();
//            main.playerturn = true;
//        }
//    }
    public static void wincheck()
    {
        if(board.button1.getText().equals("X"))
        {
            if(board.button4.getText().equals("X"))
            {
                if(board.button7.getText().equals("X"))
                {
                    playerwon = true;
                    computerwon = false;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player wins, good for you.");
                }
            }
        }
        if(board.button1.getText().equals("X"))
        {
            if(board.button5.getText().equals("X"))
            {
                if(board.button9.getText().equals("X"))
                {
                    playerwon = true;
                    computerwon = false;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player wins, good for you.");
                }
            }
        }
        if(board.button1.getText().equals("X"))
        {
            if(board.button2.getText().equals("X"))
            {
                if(board.button3.getText().equals("X"))
                {
                    playerwon = true;
                    computerwon = false;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player wins, good for you.");
                }
            }
        }
        if(board.button3.getText().equals("X"))
        {
            if(board.button5.getText().equals("X"))
            {
                if(board.button7.getText().equals("X"))
                {
                    playerwon = true;
                    computerwon = false;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player wins, good for you.");
                }
            }
        }
        if(board.button3.getText().equals("X"))
        {
            if(board.button6.getText().equals("X"))
            {
                if(board.button9.getText().equals("X"))
                {
                    playerwon = true;
                    computerwon = false;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player wins, good for you.");
                }
            }
        }
        if(board.button7.getText().equals("X"))
        {
            if(board.button8.getText().equals("X"))
            {
                if(board.button9.getText().equals("X"))
                {
                    playerwon = true;
                    computerwon = false;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player wins, good for you.");
                }
            }
        }
        if(board.button4.getText().equals("X"))
        {
            if(board.button5.getText().equals("X"))
            {
                if(board.button6.getText().equals("X"))
                {
                    playerwon = true;
                    computerwon = false;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player wins, good for you.");
                }
            }
        }
        if(board.button2.getText().equals("X"))
        {
            if(board.button5.getText().equals("X"))
            {
                if(board.button8.getText().equals("X"))
                {
                    playerwon = true;
                    computerwon = false;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player wins, good for you.");
                }
            }
        }
        if(board.button1.getText().equals("O"))
        {
            if(board.button4.getText().equals("O"))
            {
                if(board.button7.getText().equals("O"))
                {
                    playerwon = false;
                    computerwon = true;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Computer wins, you suck.");
                }
            }
        }
        if(board.button1.getText().equals("O"))
        {
            if(board.button5.getText().equals("O"))
            {
                if(board.button9.getText().equals("O"))
                {
                    playerwon = false;
                    computerwon = true;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Computer wins, you suck.");
                }
            }
        }
        if(board.button1.getText().equals("O"))
        {
            if(board.button2.getText().equals("O"))
            {
                if(board.button3.getText().equals("O"))
                {
                    playerwon = false;
                    computerwon = true;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Computer wins, you suck.");
                }
            }
        }
        if(board.button3.getText().equals("O"))
        {
            if(board.button5.getText().equals("O"))
            {
                if(board.button7.getText().equals("O"))
                {
                    playerwon = false;
                    computerwon = true;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Computer wins, you suck.");
                }
            }
        }
        if(board.button3.getText().equals("O"))
        {
            if(board.button6.getText().equals("O"))
            {
                if(board.button9.getText().equals("O"))
                {
                    playerwon = false;
                    computerwon = true;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Computer wins, you suck.");
                }
            }
        }
        if(board.button7.getText().equals("O"))
        {
            if(board.button8.getText().equals("O"))
            {
                if(board.button9.getText().equals("O"))
                {
                    playerwon = false;
                    computerwon = true;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Computer wins, you suck.");
                }
            }
        }
        if(board.button4.getText().equals("O"))
        {
            if(board.button5.getText().equals("O"))
            {
                if(board.button6.getText().equals("O"))
                {
                    playerwon = false;
                    computerwon = true;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Computer wins, you suck.");
                }
            }
        }
        if(board.button2.getText().equals("O"))
        {
            if(board.button5.getText().equals("O"))
            {
                if(board.button8.getText().equals("O"))
                {
                    playerwon = false;
                    computerwon = true;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Computer wins, you suck.");
                }
            }
        }
        if (playerwon == true || computerwon == true)
        {
            board.setVisible(false);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "play again");
//            board.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code which calls the method `computerTurn()`? I can't see any.

Comment: You should look up standard naming conventions for Java. It helps others read your code.

Comment: i dont have anything call computerTurn() but how would i call it so that it only goes after the player has? and would i need to call it in the public static void main(String[] args)? or some where else?

Comment: could i call it in side the button actions?

Comment: Why do you have 9 methods with the same code?? I suggest you to refactor your code, it will be a mess to update it.

Comment: Did you create `JButton`s and then `addActionListener()`s to them?

Comment: i edited the post to show all the code i have